# Mysql select * from a where doesnt exist in b

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having problems with constructing a query which filters out posts from table a, that already existing in table b.

Table A:

```
 `bok_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tid` time NOT NULL,
 `datum` date NOT NULL,
 `datum_end` date NOT NULL,
 `framtid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `h_adress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `l_adress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `kund` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `typ` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `bil` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
 `sign` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `tilldelad` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `skapad` datetime NOT NULL,
 `endrad` datetime NOT NULL,
 `endrad_av` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `kommentar` text NOT NULL,
 `weektype` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `Monday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Tuesday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Wednesday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Thursday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Friday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Saturday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Sunday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `avbokad` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `unika_kommentarer` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `bok_id` (`bok_id`)
```

Table B:

```
 `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bok_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `tid` time NOT NULL,
 `datum` date NOT NULL,
 `datum_end` date NOT NULL,
 `framtid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `h_adress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `l_adress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `kund` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `typ` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `bil` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
 `sign` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `tilldelad` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `skapad` datetime NOT NULL,
 `endrad` datetime NOT NULL,
 `endrad_av` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `kommentar` text NOT NULL,
 `weektype` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `Monday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Tuesday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Wednesday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Thursday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Friday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Saturday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Sunday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `avbokad` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `unika_kommentarer` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
```

What i want is a query which hides all rows in Table A which exists in table B IF Table B.tilldelad=Requested Date. (f.e 2013-09-30)

Im not sure this makes any sense?

What i want is to filter out period bookings as they have been executed and therefore exists in table b which indicates it has been.

Since its recurring events the same bok_id can exists SEVERAL times in table B, but only ONCE in table A...

```
SELECT * FROM bokningar 
WHERE bokningar.datum <= '2013-09-30' 
AND bokningar.datum_end >= '2013-09-30' 
AND bokningar.typ >= '2' 
AND bokningar.weektype = '1' 
AND bokningar.Monday = '1' ## Monday this is dynamically changed to current date 
AND bokningar.avbokad < '1' 
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tilldelade WHERE tilldelade.tilldelad = '2013-09-30' )
```

The above code does the trick regarding filtering out rows not in table B, however, if one row in table B has the current date, all results are filtered out. 
Only rows with corresponding bok_id's is supposted to get filtered out.

Any thoughts on how to do that? Perhaps a Distinct select?

Comment: You want records present in 1st not present in 2nd ? right

Comment: 1. You are using VARCHAR to store dates. 2. You are doing something wrong if you need to create columns `Monday` to `Sunday`

Comment: @AshutoshArya Yes. I want all the reults from Table A that doesnt exist in Table B.

Comment: Martin, instead of attempting to edit one of the answers, please update your own question with the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, NOT IN subselects are quite expensive in querying time.  This can normally be handled by doing a LEFT-JOIN and Keeping only those where the other table IS NULL like...

```
SELECT * 
   FROM 
      bokningar 
         LEFT JOIN tilldelade 
            on bokningar.bok_id = tilldelade.bok_id
           AND tilldelade.tilldelad = '2013-09-30'
   WHERE 
          bokningar.datum <= '2013-09-30' 
      AND bokningar.datum_end >= '2013-09-30' 
      AND bokningar.typ >= '2' 
      AND bokningar.weektype = '1' 
      AND bokningar.Monday = '1' ## Monday this is dynamically changed to current date 
      AND bokningar.avbokad < '1' 
      AND tilldelade.bok_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This Seems to work very well. Im getting the expected result, however, even though i get the correct number of rows returned, none of them contains any data? My old fetch_array simply wont work. Do i need to change anything in order to fetch the data correctly?

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['datum']; }

Comment: Is it because they have the same rownames? How do i select which table to fetch data from? I only need to show data from table Bokningar..

Comment: @Martin, sorry I couldn't respond earlier... just woke up.  Anyhow, don't forget to upcheck/checkmark the answer so others know your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.tilldelad=Requested Date
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB 
                WHERE TABLEB.tilldelad=Requested Date
                  AND TABLEA.bok_id = TABLEB.bok_id
                  AND...)
```

Comment: It works as far as filtering out result not in table b, but when one or more row in table b contain tilldelad=Requested Date i get 0 results instead of just narrowing that specific one out...

Comment: It must also be specific (using bok_id) in some way, to prevent all rows in table A to get filtered out..... Any suggestions?

Comment: SELECT * FROM bokningar 
    WHERE bokningar.datum <= '2013-09-30' 
    AND bokningar.datum_end >= '2013-09-30' 
    AND bokningar.typ >= '2' 
    AND bokningar.weektype = '1' 
    AND bokningar.Monday = '1'  ## Monday this is dynamically changed to current date
    AND bokningar.avbokad < '1' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tilldelade WHERE tilldelade.tilldelad = '2013-09-30' )

Comment: Maybee a DISTINCT query or something to make sure it only hides when the bok:id is corresponding?

Comment: @Martin I added the bok_id-condition in subquery. Just add some more conditions as needed to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works lite a charm but takes a long time to execute. (1-2 secs) and i really cant afford it taking that long.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do set operations.

A simple minus Query would solve your problem here.

```
Select * from tableA
minus
Select * from tableB;
```

This would display all data in tableA which is not present in tableB.
You can read more about it over here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29

For your specific case, try this :

```
Select * from tableA A
minus
Select * from tableB B where B.tilldelad='3013-09-30';
```

Comment: This won't do when tableA and tableB have different columns or even different values in those columns.

Comment: Both the table structure looks similar from the example he has provided.

Comment: tableA is missing the id-column of tableB and even if the structure is the same the contained data may be completely different...

Comment: @MevinBabu the only difference is that table B has one extra row which is id, since table B can hold serveral rows with the same bok_id

Comment: A minus query would solve the problem, but it has to be in a subquery.

Comment: @DanBracuk And how would that query look? Im not having any luck trying.